# Cant load picture from Firebase Storage to an Imageview

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am uploading a picture to Firebase storage in my app. It uploads fine and can be viewed in firebase storage online. When i'm trying to fetch it and show it in an image view, it does not show up in the image view instead the image view vanishes as well. I have tried this with Piccaso and glide and nothing is working.  The code is attached below

Uploading Code:

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

            uri = data.getData();

            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);




                profile_image = findViewById(R.id.profileimage);
                profile_image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);



                imageRef=storageReference.child(userID);
                imageRef.putFile(uri)
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                //if the upload is successful
                                //hiding the progress dialog
                                //and displaying a success toast
                                //dismissDialog();

                                profilePicUrl = taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl().toString();
                            }
                        })
                        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                                //if the upload is not successful
                                //hiding the progress dialog
                                // dismissDialog();
                                //and displaying error message
                                Toast.makeText(profile.this, exception.getCause().getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }


                        });















            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Download and loading into image view Code:

```
        fbstorage=FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        storageReference=fbstorage.getReference();
        imageRef=storageReference.child(userID);
        final String h=imageRef.getDownloadUrl().toString();

        storageReference.child(userID).getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {

                Toast.makeText(profile.this, "hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Picasso.with(profile.this).load(h).into(profile_image);

            }
        });
```

Comment: Have you tried to set the image to the view right inside `onSuccess()` when uploading the file?

Comment: @AlexMamo yes, same problem

Comment: Why are you loading `h` instead of the uri you just retrieved?

Answer (score 0):

try it with glide .. this code works fine with me

```
  StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("folderName"+"/"+thePicName);
    Glide.with(context.getApplicationContext())
            .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
            .load(storageReference)
            .asBitmap()
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
            .priority(Priority.IMMEDIATE)
            .into(new BitmapImageViewTarget(pic) {
                @Override
                protected void setResource(Bitmap resource) {
                    RoundedBitmapDrawable drawable = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(context.getResources(),
                            Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(resource, 150, 150, false));
                    drawable.setCircular(false);
                    pic.setImageDrawable(drawable);
                }
            });
```